# Can't combine ggplot of shapefiles including polygons and spatialpoints

Tags: r, plot, geospatial, polygon, shapefile

I downloaded three different shapefiles of the city chicago. Now i wanted to combine them and plot them together. Only the ward-offices do not plot. '''Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S4 object with class SpatialPointsDataFrame'''

The first two are polygons and the third is point oriented...

this is my code:

```
#setting directiories
chicagodir = 'Community Areas/'
chicagoshp = paste(chicagodir, "geo_export_b982773b-13a7-4b96-827d-d969f0695777.shp", sep = "")
chicagoread =readOGR(chicagoshp)
plot(chicagoread)


#Wardprecints facilities 
wardprecinctsdir = 'WardPrecincts/'
wardprecinctsshp = paste(wardprecinctsdir, "WardPrecincts.shp", sep = "")
wardprecinctsshpread =readOGR(wardprecinctsshp)
plot(wardprecinctsshpread)

#Ward Offices - Map - Exportable
wardofficesdir = 'Ward Offices - Map - Exportable/'
wardofficesshp = paste(wardofficesdir, "geo_export_b47221aa-0cc1-45db-8a3c-3e6ba72dccf1.shp", sep = "")
wardofficesshpread = readOGR(wardofficesshp)
plot(wardofficesshpread)


chicago_transform <- spTransform(chicagoread, CRS("+proj=longlat +init=epsg:4326"))
wardpre_transform <-spTransform(wardprecinctsshpread, CRS("+proj=longlat +init=epsg:4326"))
wardoff_transform <-spTransform(wardofficesshpread, CRS("+proj=longlat +init=epsg:4326"))


combinedplot = ggplot() +
  geom_path(data = chicago_transform, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  labs(title = "Plot of Chicago",
       x = "long", y = "lat") +# Because we don't need x and y labels do we?
  #add specific wardprecinctsshpread and wardoffices
  geom_polygon(data=wardpre_transform, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, color="red")) +
  geom_polygon(data=wardoff_transform, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, color="blue"))
combinedplot
'''
```

How do I resolve this, the plotting of points to the 2 polygons? thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the ward office data is different as points. You can just use `as.data.frame` on `SpatialPointsDataFrame` for plotting.

Note that instead of `lat` and `long` you need `latitude` and `longitude` (really y and x coordinates).

Otherwise, let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

chicagoread =readOGR("geo_export_210c4709-68df-496d-8b9c-8f7484608bc9.shp")
plot(chicagoread)

wardprecinctsshpread =readOGR("WardPrecincts.shp")
plot(wardprecinctsshpread)

wardofficesshpread = readOGR("geo_export_10f18171-8b13-4022-8d57-08d3b9bb0027.shp")
plot(wardofficesshpread)

chicago_transform <- spTransform(chicagoread, CRS("+proj=longlat +init=epsg:4326"))
wardpre_transform <- spTransform(wardprecinctsshpread, CRS("+proj=longlat +init=epsg:4326"))
wardoff_transform <- spTransform(wardofficesshpread, CRS("+proj=longlat +init=epsg:4326"))

combinedplot = ggplot() +
  geom_path(data = chicago_transform, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  labs(title = "Plot of Chicago", x = "long", y = "lat") +
  geom_polygon(data=wardpre_transform, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color="red") +
  geom_point(data=as.data.frame(wardoff_transform), aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), color="blue") +
  theme_bw()

combinedplot
```

[image: chicago ward offices map]